# Reset the position of jQuery UI draggable element when disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to reset the position of a jQuery draggable element after I disable draggable with dblclick. My problem is that when I remove the inline styles that draggable creates they will not come back when I enable draggable again.

This is what I do now:

```
$("span.spread").dblclick(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("draggable");
    if ($(this).data('draggable')) {
        $(this).draggable('option', 'disabled') ? $(this).draggable('enable') : $(this).draggable('disable');
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    } else {
        $(this).draggable();
    }
});
```

I probably need to removeAttr somewhere else in the code but my experience with jQuery is limited so I can't seem to figure out where.

Here you can check out a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bQuf8/

Comment: What about a jsfiddle?

Comment: @A.Wolff Here you can check out a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bQuf8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know if i understand correctly your question.
But if you want to reset the original position of the div after disabling draggable
here is a my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/HtZ66/)
If i did not understand your question, i'm sorry you waste time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("span.spread").draggable({disabled:true});   
 $("span.spread").dblclick(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("draggable");
        if($(this).hasClass('draggable')){
            $("span.spread").draggable({disabled:false});
            }else{
            $("span.spread").draggable({disabled:true});
            $(this).css({'position':'relative','top':'','left':''});
        };
    }); 
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve! Sorry for not being clear enough.